# How to update a Magento 2 cart?

Tags: magento2, cart

Maybe I don't know enough about Magento, but is there not a setting for allowing a cart update?

I have a Magento 2.3 site, and when I add items to the cart, it opens up a minicart with the quantities. But, when I close the minicart, and then go back to the cart and update the quantities, it end ups doubling all the quantities, instead of just updating what has been changed.

Is there not an "update cart" option built into Magento?

Comment: That's the more likely your customization issue. You can install fresh Magento and compare. By default you can add/update from minicart and shopping cart page.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try that tomorrow and see what’s up and report back.